# Internal linkage of static or const definitions in c++ header files (code bloat, memory consumption)

Tags: c++, performance, linkage

I did some tests with clang. I'am working on a very large code base and we have a lot of constant definitions of Strings that are shown in the UI (for simplicity I omit the translation mechanism, lets assume our UI is English only).

Variant 1 in header:

```
const char* const authorName = "Hello World";
```

Every translation unit will have a copy of that string. After linking, the resulting executable includes only one "Hello World" string (you can check that in an hex editor).

Variant 2 in header:

```
const std::string authorName ("Hello World");"
```

Every translation unit will have a copy of the "Hello World" string (you can search for the string in a hex editor). After linking, the resulting executable includes only one "Hello World" string (you can check that in a hex editor too). But something annoying happens: for every single translation unit that has a dependency to the header file that defines the const std::string a std::string object is created during program initialisation. I wrote a small test class in our source code that has a vector of 1 MB size. Defining a static variable of that test class in a header that is known by a lot of translation unit increases our runtime memory from 130 MB to 2 GB.

Can someone explain me in detail what happens under the hood? Has Variant 1 the same behaviour? Does it mean that during program initialisation for every translation unit that includes the header with the const char* const pointer memory is allocated, like it is for the std::string?

-----Edit----

I just did another test:
I defined in a header file exactly one variable:

```
const char* const stringOne = "Hello World!";
```

I added two header/cpp pairs providing a method to print the address of the stringOne variable (both cpp files include my header with the stringOne variable).

```
void print ()
{
    std::cout << &stringOne << '\n';
}
```

And guess what: they print different addresses. So it seems it is the same behaviour as with the string class. For each translation unit that includes the header with the stringOne variable memory is allocated (8 bytes for 64 bit). The string literal itself only exists once in the binary (you can check that with a hex editor). This means when 100 translation units include my header I get a memory overhead of (100 * 8 Bytes). When I declare the stringOne variable extern both functions output the same address.
Can someone explain me in detail what the compiler does here? It seems it's always a really bad idea to define internal linkage variables in a header file...
And by the way, I also tried it out with a constexpr variable. It's the same behaviour.

Comment: A literal string has no side effects so redundant copies can be removed. A `std::string` can not be `constexpr` since it uses dynamically allocated memory, and so an instantiation can possibly have side effects, and there is some language in the standard that forbids removing instances of user-defined types where constructor might have side effect. I guess a decent compiler could have special support for `std::string`. But you can simply declare it with extern linkage, by using C++17 `inline`. Or employ any of the pre-C++17 tricks for same effect, e.g. dummy template, or Meyers' singleton.

Comment: Relevant term: ["constant folding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding).

Comment: Thanks for the info Alf